# Using php how do I create playlists and queues for a flash mp3 player?

Tags: php, flash, mp3

Are there any guides for this? Can I send music links to an mp3 player with javascript, build queues, etc?  I wish I could do this with the HTML5 audio tags, but the browser compatibility is just ridiculous right now.

Edit, to clarify the playlists/queues would be built by the user as they are browsing music, not some pre-generated playlist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Playlists are often text formats. But which of them highly depends on the player software that you want to use.

The most common textual formats are [.pls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29)  and [.m3u](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), and only occasionally .xspf. If it's a flash player, then the input list might just be a space separated object params list. I don't see why it also couldn't just consume an RSS feed with mp3 urls, or even poll an json feed.

Here's one using an XSPF playlist: http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/